# Academic Search API devuelve json con el mensaje "This API is decommissioned." y code: gone

Tags: api

Llevo un tiempo usando la API de Microsoft Academic para realizar búsquedas y desde hace unas dos semanas estoy recibiendo el código 410 a mis solicitudes con un json:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Gone",
    "message": "This API is decommissioned."
  }
}

He comprobado las API keys en la cuenta de azure y están bien. También he probado a realizar la petición en su Playground ([Url del endpoint evaluate que uso](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03/console))  obteniendo los mismos resultados.

Dado que no prestan soporte en las cuentas básicas y no he encontrado ningúna entrada relacionada en los foros, no sé si es que realmente la API esta fuera de servicio o si se trata de un error. ¿Alguien sabe algo al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que han cambiado una API por otra, de Academic Search han pasado a Academic Knowledge. Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic/articles/sign-academic-knowledge-api/) y [esta](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-academic-knowledge) es la página de la API

Comment: Gracias Javier. Has sido de gran ayuda ya que esta gente no nos ha avisado por ningún medio. En fin, a ver si basta con generar las nuevas claves o un simple cambio de endpoint, porque por lo que he podido leer parece que todo lo que hay en esta nueva plataforma es "experimental".

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Encantado de poder ayudar Puedes dar la respuesta como válida, si quieres